# Problem in subView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
 -(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id) sender {
[textInfo resignFirstResponder];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:(UITableViewController*)informationTableView];// don't Work 
 }
```

expected expression before 'informationTableView'

I want to have this view when he clicks on the keyboard end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your below statement is wrong

```
  [self.view addSubview:(UITableViewController*)informationTableView];// will never work
```

Check correct one below.

```
UIView* MyView = (UITableViewController*)informationTableView.view ;

[self.view addSubview:MyView];
```

MyView must a subclass of `UIView`,

Q. Let me know the class name and it's super class name of `informationTableView`.

Comment: the same problem i have a TableView and i want to view him when textFieldDoneEditing

Comment: @PasstissiPhone: Rest of your code in textFieldDoneEditing look pretty good just replace   [self.view addSubview:(UITableViewController*)informationTableView];// will never work
       with  UIView* MyView = (UITableViewController*)informationTableView.view ;

[self.view addSubview:MyView];

Answer (score 1):

If UITableViewController is UIViewController you have to do like this

`[self.view addSubview:[(UITableViewController*)informationTableView].view];`

Hope this helps.